# What substitution should i make for this integral

Tags: calculus, substitution

$$
\int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{x+ \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{3}+1}}}dx\>
$$

Wolfram alpha gives its answer as 3.01376.

Can any one provide me a solution for this?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is likely to be evaluating it numerically.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get u

Comment: I'm saying that I don't think that Wolfram is giving you an exact result. The 3.01376 is just an approximation. Wolfram Alpha is definitely not evaluating this integral by finding an anti-derivative for the integrand, since if you remove the limits of integration then Wolfram Alpha is unable to find the integral. There are obviously other ways to find the values of definite integrals, however, so this should not be taken to say that it will be impossible. There may be some clever trickery that allows you to get an exact solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Too long for a comment:** Imagine the much simpler integrand $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}~.~$

A trivial trigonometric or hyperbolic substitution of the form $x=\tan t$ or $x=\sinh u$

yields a closed form expression for its primitive, in terms of elementary functions.

By applying what seems to be only a slight modification, and changing its form to

$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2}2+1}}$, the result becomes inexpressible without the aid of [hypergeometric 

 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), or [incomplete beta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function), or [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) : take your pick. The expression

in question, following the hyperbolic substitution $x=\sqrt2~\sinh t$, can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izRPb.png).

$($Trigonometric substitutions yield even uglier results$)$. Replacing $\bf1$ by $\sqrt{\dfrac{x^3}3+1}$ ,

even these special functions are unable to help us express the anti-derivative. For more

information on this topic, see [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).